# How do I climb up a ledge

Tags: unity, c#, game-design, monodevelop

I am currently working on a 3D game in unity. I want my player to be able to grab a ledge, and climb up on it. Please I will like to inform you that I am new to this, so a basic and easy to follow example will be nice. thanks

Comment: [I downvoted because no attempt was made](http://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/). Google has plenty [information about this](http://www.lmgtfy.com/?q=unity+climb+script)

Comment: I actually checked, and I ave been checking for the last 2 weeks. what I saw on google was a player hanging on a ledge but none was actually climbing on the ledge. I just need a clear cut explanation. I'm new to this.

Comment: Hi David, and welcome to GameDev.StackExchange. Remember that users here have never seen your game before. So we don't know if you're working in 2D or 3D, 1st person, over-the-shoulder, isometric, whether your style is realistic or cartoony, or any other details that might impact how we approach a ledge climb. Please ensure you always include information about your game context in your question. Also try to break down the problem: do you need help 1) Detecting / tagging ledges? 2) Attaching the player to the ledge 3) Animating the climb 4) Resuming normal control state at the top...? etc.

Comment: You may also want to investigate what defines a ledge.  Are you going to predefine it in your maps, or attempt to make a function that will calculate if a given area contains a ledge?

Comment: okay, so you mean, I have to finish with the building of the map before I can decide on where I want it to climb ?  @phflack

Comment: Not quite, but you should decide if areas are going to be marked as ledges, or if you're going to use an algorithm to check if the player is trying to climb a ledge.  If you're defining ledges, you can add them to your prefabs, ie every crate might have 4 ledge points defined on it (similar to jump points for AI)

Comment: is it possible I get your email ?

Answer (score 1):

There are loads of ways to do this, i assume you are using Inverse Kinematics for your player. I know a series of videos on youtube that explains the whole process on how to make a climbing system from schratch here is the [link](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL1bPKmY0c-wlGdXHNwGLnREWJcb7-4Rvo) this playlist is really good, i learned a lot of things from this guy ;)

Comment: thamnk you so much. ill check it

Comment: This is currently a link-only answer. If the playlist URL ever changes or it becomes unavailable, a user won't be able to get any benefit from what's written here. Please consider editing the answer to include at least a rough outline of the solution, so it serves as a useful summary even on its own.

Comment: @DMGregory the problem is, i don't know too much about this "climbing mechanic" so i don't think i would be able to give a good enough answer to his aproblem as the link i provided does